# OptionMenu __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an issue trying to divide words with (1) or (2) in the end that contain in `Text` box into 2 `OptionMenu`. The error is `__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'` which occures in 26th (and 27th) line: `opt1=OptionMenu(root,var1,*spl()[0])`. Will appreciate if you take a look!

```
root=Tk()
text=Text(root,height=10,width=40)
text.pack()

def spl():
    Get=text.get(1.0,END)
    Get=Get.split()    
    A=[]
    B=[]
    for i in range(len(Get)):
        if Get[i][:-4:-1] == '(1)':
            A.append(Get[i])
        elif Get[i][:-4:-1] == '(2)':
            B.append(Get[i])
        else:
            continue
    return A,B

btn=Button(root,command=spl,text='Refresh')
btn.pack()
var1=IntVar()
var1.set('1st list')
var2=IntVar()
var2.set('2nd list')
opt1=OptionMenu(root,var1,*spl()[0])
opt2=OptionMenu(root,var2,*spl()[1])
opt1.pack()
opt2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you please post the full error traceback? Also, could you possibly give your variables / function more obvious names?

Comment: You example is missing a critical detail: the import statements. Are you using the tkinter optionmenu or the ttk optionmenu?

Comment: I use tkinter's optionmenu

Comment: When you run this code, `spl` is executed directly in order to populate the OptionMenu. However, since the Text widget is still empty at that point, it will return empty lists. You cannot make an OptionMenu without options, so you get the error.

Comment: Also, `Get[i][:-4:-1]` is wrong. It does get the last three characters, but in reverse order. So when a string ends with `(1)`, you get `)1(` and your comparison will never be true. Use `Get[i][-3:]`.

Comment: @fhdrsdg Oh, that's pretty useful, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @fhdrsdg i fixed this code. Maybe my way of fixing it isn't professional but at least it works. (I didn't write an exception for empty arrays A and B but i think it shouldn't be difficult).

```
root=Tk()
text=Text(root,height=10,width=40)
text.pack()

def spl():
    Get=text.get(1.0,END)
    Get=Get.split(',') 
    A=[]
    B=[]
    for i in range(len(Get)):
        if Get[i][-3:] == '(1)':
            A.append(Get[i])
        elif Get[i][-3:] == '(2)':
            B.append(Get[i])
        else:
            continue
    global opt1,opt2
    opt1.destroy()
    opt2.destroy()
    opt1=OptionMenu(root,var1,*A)
    opt1.pack()
    opt2=OptionMenu(root,var2,*B)    
    opt2.pack()


var1=IntVar()
var1.set('1st list')
var2=IntVar()
var2.set('2nd list')
opt1=OptionMenu(root,var1,value='0')
opt2=OptionMenu(root,var2,value='0')
btn=Button(root,command=spl,text='Refresh')
btn.pack()

opt1.pack()
opt2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

the third param of "OptionMenu" is tuple. always tuple, not one element

```
def spl():
    ...
    return A,B
opt1=OptionMenu(root,var1, *tuple(spl()))
```

Comment: So what should i do to make for example first OptionMenu with param A?

Comment: ? The `OptionMenu` initiation statement looks like `def __init__(self, master, variable, value, *values, **kwargs)`. So the third argument is `value`, which is expected to be a string. All unnamed arguments after that are collected into `values`, which then becomes a tuple of strings. After that, the only keyword argument that is allowed is `command`.